# cygwin rsync between local disks fails with rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12)

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I'm using cygwin rsync to backup my local disk to a USB 3.0 external disk. Frequently, the process fails with the following error:

```
alex/Pictures/AppData/Lightroom/Current
Db/Lightroom
Previews.lrdata/0/03E9/03E9CB0E-96B7-4602-BBAE-CBF820381731-514d8ee17112aeee3852fda5392a8ee8.lr-preview.noindex
    rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4092 bytes to socket
[sender]: Software caused connection
abort (113)
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (35523 bytes received so far)
[sender]
    rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at
/home/lapo/package/rsync-3.0.8-1/src/rsync-3.0.8/io.c(601)
[sender=3.0.8]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "simpleBackupTest.py", line 23, in <module>
        subprocess.check_call(rsyncCommand,
shell=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py",
line 498, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'rsync -v
--log-file=/cygdrive/c/data/logs/rsync/rsync_backup_task.log
-a /cygdrive/c/Users/ /cygdrive/j/backup/Users' returned
non-zero exit status 12
```

The local disk seems to be available before & after this error, so I don't think its the drive being disconnected.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: unfortunately, I never have had much luck with rsync on cygwin. You might have better luck with some of the standalone rsync binaries for windows (google). PS. Please do not use quotation for preformatted text. Indent with 4+ spaces instead of `> `

Comment: Are you using the latest Cygwin version (1.7.9)? There have been fixes in this area recently.

Comment: thanks for the comments - sorry for the delay I've been out of town. @sehe I'd be interested in any links you've got for the standalone native rsync binaries.

Comment: BTW, I've worked around this a little by starting to look at using robocopy instead...